# Accessing an existing table with connectionString

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity, connection-string

I'm writing a web application that will be accessing/updating several existing tables in a database. Currently, I am trying to access a local version of the database on SQL express for testing purposes but cannot get the connection set up properly after searching how to do it. My web.config file currently has the connection string set up as follows:

```
<add name="ContractDBContext" 
     connectionString="Data Source=SBUWMPB01FHSM\SQLEXPRESS;
                       Initial Catalog=12-2013 Derivative TrackingSQL;
                       Integrated Security=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

This is the code for the class that models the DB table:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace ForeignExchange.Models
{
    [Table("AccountingData")]
    public class Contract
    {
        [Key][Required]
        public int TKRContractID { get; set; }
        public int AsOfMonth { get; set; }
        public int AsOfQuarter { get; set; }
        public int ASOfYear { get; set; }
        public double CurrentMoFMVChg { get; set; }
        public double LTDFMVChg { get; set; }
        public double AccumulatedOCI { get; set; }
        public double AccumulatedDerivAsset { get; set; }
        public double AccumulatedPL { get; set; }
        public double AccumulatedFAS5 { get; set; }
        public double HistoricalSpotRate { get; set; }
        public double HistoricalHedgedRate { get; set; }
    }
    [Table("AccountingData")]
    public class ContractDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

After writing the two sections of code given above, I used the "Add controller" automated dialog to generate the CRUD .cshtml pages and controller called ContractsController. Once I run the code and try to access the generated index page that should display the table, I get the following error on the line

```
return View(db.Contracts.ToList())

EntityCommandExecutionExcception
An error occurred while executing the command definition.
System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146232004
  Message=An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
  Source=System.Data.Entity
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
       at System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalQuery`1.GetEnumerator()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at ForeignExchange.Controllers.ContractsController.Index() in C:\Users\stonejo\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ForeignExchange\ForeignExchange\Controllers\ContractsController.cs:line 21
       at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
  InnerException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
       HResult=-2146232060
       Message=Invalid column name 'AccumulatedFAS5'.
       Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
       ErrorCode=-2146232060
       Class=16
       LineNumber=11
       Number=207
       Procedure=""
       Server=SBUWMPB01FHSM\SQLEXPRESS
       State=1
       StackTrace:
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
            at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
            at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
       InnerException:
```

Connection strings and web based apps are totally new to me, so I appreciate any help that someone can offer me for this. Thanks for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: To me, `Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0` should be `Data Source=ServerName\DbName`. But I might be wrong

Comment: Fwiw sometimes when I have conn string issues in visual studio I go to Data Sources, add new data source and let the wizard figure it out.

Comment: @T.S. I've tried going with my PCname\SQLEXPRESS, but encountered the same error.

Comment: @EricScherrer The option is greyed out for me, and some searching has shown that the "add data source" option can't be used in a web app.

Comment: Open a new instance of visual studio, create a new solution/project just to get the result then copy/paste it into your original solution.

Comment: @EricScherrer Good tip! That generated a new error, so progress is being made! I've updated the error log and connection string to reflect this change.

Comment: From the error it looks like you are now connected. Now you just have to work through this error: Invalid column name 'AccumulatedFAS5'.

Comment: @EricScherrer It works now! Thanks for your help! After correcting the connection string, I just had to fix the typo mentioned and it worked.

Comment: No problem - converted to answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in visual studio go to Data Sources, add new data source and let the wizard figure it out. If you need to, open a new instance of Visual Studio, create a new solution/project just to get the result then copy/paste it into your original solution.